# Как рандомно выбрать из цикла foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

Здравствуйте.

У меня стоит задача рандомно выбрать из цикла `foreach` id сотрудника, при этом не учитывать старый id сотрудника. На рандоме застыл...

```
if($queryStaffAccess = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `staff` WHERE id_cabinet = '$id_cabinet'")) {
        if($queryStaffAccess->num_rows) {
            while($StaffAccess = $queryStaffAccess->fetch_assoc()) {
                $StaffAccessBuffer[] = $StaffAccess;
            }
        }
    } 

    foreach($StaffAccessBuffer as $StaffAccessValue) {
        if ($StaffAccessValue['id_staff'] !== $id_staff_old and $StaffAccessValue['application'] == '1'){
            //выбрать рандомно          
        }

    }
```

P.S. Все в целях экономии запросов к базе, так как сейчас идут два запроса на каждую заявку, а их сотни тысяч. Получается при 1000 проверяемых заявок к базе еще 2000 дополнительных запросов в минуту.

Comment: неудачников отсеиваете? :)

Comment: @splash58 нет, просто переназначение нового ответственного, если с заявкой ничего не делали... Менеджеры либо ответят на заявку либо эта штука их замучает до смерти =)

Comment: А `$StaffAccessBuffer` далее как-то используется? Если нет, то непонятно, зачем он вообще нужен, если поставленную задачу можно решить единственным запросом `... WHERE <все нужные условия> ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Yaant смысл в том, что в цикле обработки может быть несколько тысяч заявок (поверьте) на каждую заявку идут два запроса (не знаю как сделать без двух) т.е. если 1000 заявок обрабатываем внутри цикла обрабоки заявок 2 запроса к базе это +2000 запросов. И это как бы не хорошо. По этому можно выше занести данные сотрудников их не может быть больше 50 по этому надо уже с массивом сотрудников работать. Получается за работу скрипта к базе staff подключаемся всего один раз, а не 2000 раз...

Comment: @Yaant ваш приведенный пример вот в данный момент стоит. Там просто сложное условие выборки сотрудников,сначала надо выбрать всех тех у кого есть права получения заявок при этом исключить старого сотрудника.

Comment: Ну, не зная всей задачи, конечно, сложно что-то говорить наверняка, но есть смутные подозрения, что все это может быть решаемо буквально несколькими SQL-запросами вместо тысяч. Может Вы не с той стороны подходите к вопросу?

Comment: @Yaant  описал полностью процесс работы...

Comment: Из описания как-то совсем непонятно, что за 2 запроса требуются на заявку, почему в минуту проверяется всего 1000 заявок, если их сотни тысяч, и т.п. Неясна структура данных в базе (разве что о таблице `staff` можно сделать некоторые предположения), что там хранится, и какая обработка требуется. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант сделать так

```
SELECT name
  FROM random AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM random)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

Либо сделать `shuffle`  на массив $StaffAccessValue и потом выбирать по очереди и делать сравнения на $StaffAccessValue['application'] == '1'

Comment: у меня смысл в том, чтобы не делать запросы внутри цикла (заявок) иначе дофига запросов. Мне нужно взять один раз список сотрудников (один раз)  перед циклом (заявок), потом уже внутри цикла (заявок) колдовать с списком сотрудников, не подключаясь к нему. Это экономит 1999 запросов